# AVAssetExportSession decode error while compressing video

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, decode, avassetexportsession

I want to compress my video before uploading it to the web service. For that I use below code, but I am getting always decode error. Can you please help me to solve this.

Code :

```
AVAssetExportSession session = AVAssetExportSession.FromAsset(asset,AVAssetExportSession.PresetLowQuality);
session.OutputUrl = outputUrl;
session.OutputFileType = AVFileType.QuickTimeMovie;
session.ExportAsynchronously(() =>
{
var exportError = session.Error;
var exportStatus = session.Status;

if (session.Status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Video Completed");
}else{
    Debug.WriteLine("Video Error");
}
});
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: @JimiLoe You can check error on this snap. [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72782351/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-08%20at%2012.09.44.png)